How to read the .smps file in pyomo or pysp
I want to utilize pyomo to solve 2stage stochastic programs (achieved from SIPLIB, which is in smps format), but how to make the smps file compatible with pyomo?
Is there any implementation? I found that pysp can transfer the pyomo model into smps, can this be done conversely?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
